# Logistic regression with multiple outcomes

Tags: regression, logistic, repeated-measures

I have a study looking at the association between a novel diagnostic measure (continuous var) and a health outcome (measured at 4 different time periods; binary). In addition, data on traditional diagnostic measures will be collected to see if it could have predicted the same health outcome, independent of the novel diagnostic tool.

My questions are:

1. Since my outcome variable is collected at 4 different times, can I still run a logistic regression?
2. To compare the predictive value of the traditional measure vs. the novel diagnostic measure, should I just compare their regression coefficients or do I need to create two separate regression models?

Comment: I think we need a bit more background. As a starting point, I would like to know if these 4 responses over the years have any restrictions|correlations. E.g: 1) is it possible to have the value 1 at year 1 and the value 0 at year 2? 2) If someone has the value 1 at year 1 does he have more chances to have value 1 at year 2 compared to someone who has the value 0 at year 1??